# Why do the http precondition header fields support multiple etags?

Tags: http, caching, etag, rfc, http-caching

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3

When would one need to check against multiple etags instead of just one?

E.g, what would be the purpose of sending a HTTP request with `If-None-Match: "etag1","etag2"`? Why would a client ever need both `"etag1"` and `"etag2"` in there? Shouldn't the client be using just the last etag received from the server for this particular resource?

Answer (score 0):

*Why would a client ever need both `etag1` and `etag2` in there?*

If the client has both `etag1` and `etag2` in its cache then it is to its advantage to send both, since that expands the range of situations in which it can skip downloading new data.

*Shouldn't the client be using just the last etag received from the server for this particular resource?*

You're thinking of a resource that, when it changes, always changes to a new value, in which case there wouldn't be any point in caching the old ones. However, that's not necessarily the case. Imagine a resource that oscillates between two states (representations), in which case caching both (and sending both ETags) means that you never have to download the data again.

Another thing to consider is that `Content-Type` can change the representation of the same resource at the same point in time. Imagine a client (an intermediate cache, say) that can handle both text and gzipped versions of a resource, and already has one of each. Sending both ETags (in conjunction with `Accept`) means that it is less likely to have to download new data.

Comment: Why would a resource oscillate between two states?

Comment: And do you know if browsers actually send multiple ETags? I haven't been able to find any information.

Comment: But from my testing, it does not seem like they do.

Comment: Aha, https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39727 really cleared my mind on this. Each ETag can be for a different variant of the same resource. so identity vs gzipped for example.

Comment: @nhooyr: I'm not sure what browsers do. Remember that HTTP is not designed specifically for browsers and web pages, there are many other use cases. The basic principle is straightforward: if you have multiple versions of a resource in your cache, then it makes sense to tell the server about all of them to increase the chance of successfully revalidating.